# Insert table into mail body

Tags: python, html, email, outlook, css-tables

I would like to add a table to a mail letter, but not as an attachment. 
Additional requirement is to fill some cells with colors, but I'm not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: what did you find in Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was that HTML code was interpreted as plain text, not HTML.
So, here is the answer:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'name@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'Tadadada'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>Place your HTML here</h2>'

mail.Send()
```

Comment: Setting HTMLBody does not work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the table as html ?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">February</td>
      <td style="color: hotpink;">$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried to add HTML code to mail as here:

`table = 
<table>
...
</table>
`
and send it, but it looks just like a plain text in resulting mail.